# How to image upload via drag and drop in django

Tags: django, image, upload

I could not find anything about django image DRAG and DROP not that for select every image separately and upload it. Do you have any idea or links. Thanks

Comment: The drap and drop feature should be implemented on template level by javascript which will give image to django-field.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.calazan.com/adding-drag-and-drop-image-uploads-to-your-django-site-in-5-minutes-with-dropzonejs/. Hope this helps.